# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Challenge Handler inside Angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using adapter-based authentication that I am trying to implement using AngularJS. I have a single realm that protects the application, and all procedures. I've defined a Login Controller that handles authentication related activities:

Note: Testing with MBS on Chrome and Worklight Development Server

```
 $scope.sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("LoginBluePageRealm");
 $scope.sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = $scope.isCustomResponse;
 $scope.sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = $scope.handleChallenge;
```

The Login view is the initial view displayed due to issuing `WL.Client.connect()`, and authentication works fine collecting credentials, and transitioning from the login view to the main menu view.

I cause the connection to the server to fail (by restarting the WL dev server), and then select an activity in the application that will invoke a protected adapter call.  I see in the JavaScript console that `$scope.isCustomResponse()` is reached, but then there is no entry into the `$scope.handleChallenge();`.

Is there any issues with defining the challenge support in $scope, or is there a requirement that they be defined at the $rootScope level.

Appreciate any advice defining authentication within AngularJS.

Comment: can you produce a demo project exhibiting the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add logs to isCustomResponse to actually see responseText/responseJson property of what it's getting? Also - before returning true/false from isCustomResponse log your response. The handleChallenge function is not invoked in case isCustomResponse returns false, so you might be missing some if.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should not define any javascript object that you would like to persist in Angular via $scope.  Angular can destroy $scope variables at any time.  Instead, wrap the challenge handler in an Angular service/factory definition since these are singletons that persist.  This is a good video I would suggest watching for Worklight + Angular. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a89W_atlhjg